# Passing data between tabbed fragment lists

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments

I have implemented:

```
public class CategoryListFragment extends ListFragment 
(Categories) Tab1

public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment
(List of crimes) Tab2
```

-- If you click on the tab it returns ALL crimes.

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment
(Individual Crime) Tab 3
```

-- If you click on the tab it returns first crime.

And the activity that hosts all of the tabs:

```
public class TabsFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener
```

What I want to implement is an `onListItemClick` on (Tab 1) "Categories" that passes the ID or string to Tab 2 so that only the crimes of that category are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already described in the official android documentation.
please follow the link and read about it there: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener is a custom interface. in your case it is something like CrimeListFragment.OnCreimeSelectedListener. And there is nothing wrong with implementing more than one interface.